# how to remove double quotations using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

how to remove all quotation from array key using jquery:

```
 var data = [{"lat":35.67842130775499,"lng":139.76254865075686}, 
 {"lat":35.67969389747307,"lng":139.76104136239624}, 
{"lat":35.68026039376082,"lng":139.76128816239623}];
```

this is my data so how to i remove double quotation from lat and lng using jquery.
currently i am using:-

```
var vrold = data.replace('"','').replace('"','');
```

but this remove only first word quotation. I want this type of data format:-

```
var newData = [{lat:35.67842130775499, lng:139.76254865075686}, 
 {lat:35.67969389747307, lng:139.76104136239624}, 
{lat:35.68026039376082, lng:139.76128816239623}];
```

Comment: X/Y problem detected! the problem is not the quotes but what you really want to do with the js object after "removing the quotes".

Comment: Don't. This is a json object. Instead, use you need to decode the json. The manner depends on if you want to use php ([json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)) or javascript ([JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse))

Comment: How is this relevant to PHP?

Comment: Why do you need that, I tested in browser console, and JS already transforms it without double quote after instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

 var data = [{
     "lat": 35.67842130775499,
     "lng": 139.76254865075686
   },
   {
     "lat": 35.67969389747307,
     "lng": 139.76104136239624
   },
   {
     "lat": 35.68026039376082,
     "lng": 139.76128816239623
   }
 ];

 var vrold = JSON.stringify(data).replace(/\"/g,"");
 console.log(vrold);

 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1myxu6wg/

Answer (score -1):

This is a correct Json format without double quot.

So you should use

var a = JSON.parse(data);

JSON.parse return Array(Object) when you use for or foreach method to process your array data.

Javascript:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

PHP:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php